# DISTINCT for only one Column and other column random?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one Table name Demodata which have two column col1 and col2. data of table is

```
col1   col2    
1        5  
1        6    
2        7    
3        8    
3        9    
4        10
```

and after **SELECT** command we need this data

```
col1    Col2    
1        5    
         6    
2        7   
3        8   
         9   
4        10
```

is this possible then what is query please guide me

Comment: Almost certainly it will be more easily achieved in whatever code is *receiving* this result set.

Comment: Except if you are reporting on the data ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN RN > 1 THEN NULL ELSE Col1 END,Col2
    FROM
    (
    SELECT *,Row_Number() Over(Partition by col1 order by col1) AS RN
    From yourTable
    ) AS T
```

Comment: The first column seems to be an `int`-column.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible.

SQL Server result sets are row based not tree based. You must have a value for each column (alternatively a NULL value).

What you can do is grouping by `col1` and run an aggregate function on the values of `col2` (possibly the `STUFF` function).

Comment: Why it's no possible?? don't confuse with tree structure

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this in SQL, using `row_number()`:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) = 1
             then col1
        end), col2
from table t
order by col1, col2;
```

Notice that the ordering is important.  The way you have written the result set, the data is ordered by `col1` and then `col2`.  Result sets do not have an inherent ordering, unless you include an `order by` clause.

Also, I have used `NULL` for the missing values.

And, finally, although this can be done in SQL, it is often preferable to do these types of manipulations on the client side.

Comment: I think the question is more about getting the data in a tree format not just getting rid of the first column value.

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou . . . I don't know why you are reading that into the question.  I think the desired results are pretty clear and I don't see anything that suggests a tree structure in the question.

Comment: I think that ordering by the second column is not what OP wants since he has stated clearly in the title that the second column should be "random".

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I got that from trying to execute a distinct on one column --> that is a tree

Comment: @TimSchmelter . . . It is irrelevant, but I interpret that as meaning "another column", not a statement about the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to select on the duplicates, an empty string, `NULL`, 0, ... ?

I presume `NULL`, you can use a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER` and `CASE` on `col1`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 
                               ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
        , col1, col2
  FROM Demodata 
)
SELECT col1 = CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN col1 ELSE NULL END, col2
FROM CTE
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5042e/1/0)</kbd>